# Retrieve content from editable ALV

Tags: grid, abap, alv

I'm developing a report that displays and editable ALV.

I set PF-STATUS, adding a 'Process' button. When this button is pressed, the content introduced in the ALV by the user should be retrieved and then processed.

This is how I'm building my ALV:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
EXPORTING
  i_callback_program       = sy-repid "program name
  i_callback_user_command  = 'USER_COMMAND' "user command subroutine name
  i_callback_pf_status_set = 'SUB_PF_STATUS'
  it_fieldcat              = it_fieldcat
  i_save                   = 'X'
TABLES
  t_outtab                 = it_input
EXCEPTIONS
  program_error            = 1
  OTHERS                   = 2.
```

However, the way I'm doing this, the retrieval comes empty. 
How can I solve this problem?

Below I have a snippet of my code when it comes to 'Process'.

```
IF r_ucomm EQ '&PROC'.

 LOOP AT it_input INTO ls_input.
   PERFORM process_data USING ls_input.
 ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.
```

Comment: Maybe not the easiest way with this function module. You must get the instance of the ALV grid control, and use the method `check_changed_data` to extract the changed data. You have lots of examples with programs `BCALV*EDIT*` (PS: these programs need data generated by program `SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR`).

Comment: Is it possible to create the ALV from `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` object ?

Answer (score 1):

After fetching the ALV grid instance run its **method 'check_changed_data'** like the example below.

```
DATA lo_grid TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.

IF r_ucomm EQ '&PROC'.
    CALL FUNCTION 'GET_GLOBALS_FROM_SLVC_FULLSCR'
        IMPORTING
            e_grid = lo_grid.

    IF lo_grid IS NOT INITIAL.
        lo_grid->check_changed_data( ).
    ENDIF.

 LOOP AT it_input INTO ls_input.
   PERFORM process_data USING ls_input.
 ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.
```

You can create the ALV grid directly, without function module 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY' by using method 'set_table_for_first_display'.

```
DATA go_grid TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.

CREATE OBJECT go_grid
    EXPORTING
        i_parent = cl_gui_custom_container=>default_screen.

go_grid->set_table_for_first_display(
    CHANGING
       it_outtab       = it_input
       it_fieldcatalog = it_fieldcat ).

...

IF r_ucomm EQ '&PROC'.
    go_grid->check_changed_data( ).
    LOOP AT it_input INTO ls_input.
        PERFORM process_data USING ls_input.
    ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove line  **REFRESH it_input.** This is removing contents of it_input therefore retrieval is empty.
You can use below code without **REFRESH it_input**

```
IF r_ucomm EQ '&PROC'.

 LOOP AT it_input INTO ls_input.
   PERFORM process_data USING ls_input.
 ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.
```

Comment: I've tried that already.
`it_input` still comes out empty even thought ALV grid had values in it.

Comment: @umar That REFRESH in the original question is very confusing, I remove it.